# mat-slide-toggle [checked] attribute doesn't seem to work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `<mat-slide-toggle>` which I defined as such :

```html
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="synchronizationState === 'ENABLED'"
                  [disabled]="!canChangeSynchronizationState"
                  formControlName="enableSynchronization"
                  #enableSynchronizationToggle
                  (change)="openConfirmSynchronizationStateDialog(enableSynchronizationToggle.checked)">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

However, when the user clicks on the toggle, it changes state not matter what (if it was checked, it goes unchecked and vice-versa), even if `synchronizationState` hasn't changed.

I've further tested the component like such :
`<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="checked" [checked]="checked"></mat-slide-toggle>`
where `checked = false;` and it appears I can still change the state of the toggle.

It looks like the mat-slide-toggle doesn't care at all about what I input in [checked], what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: why don't you just pass the syncronization state variable to the checked property `[checked]="syncronizationState"` only? 

Kindly if you can share a stackblitz of the code for a review?

Comment: It's a string which is either 'ENABLED' or 'DISABLED' so I have to check against it to get a boolean.
I'm not sure for stackblitz as we use MaterialUI, I'll edit the question to specify this